# Angular 11 trying to create a form wrapper "editor" that controls UI based on form status

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to create a reusable form editor component that shows/hides a toolbar at the bottom of the form based on if the form is dirty. The toolbar has a save button and a reset form button. Both of the buttons on the toolbar need to be controlled based on the validity of the form. I used this tutorial [here](https://netbasal.com/detect-unsaved-changes-in-angular-forms-75fd8f5f1fa6) which is great... but I want to be able to reuse the component by passing in any form.

Here is my code (notice I am creating a FormGroup and passing it directly to ContentEditorComponent as an Input. My custom dirtyCheck operator is at the bottom.)

content-editor.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'content-editor',
    template: `
        <mat-card class="card">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            <div class="footer" *ngIf="isDirty$ | async">
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid$">
            </div>
        </mat-card>
    `,
})
export class ContentEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
    @Input('formGroup') form: FormGroup;
    isDirty$: Observable<boolean>;
    source: Observable<any>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.source = of(cloneDeep(this.form.value));
        this.isDirty$ = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
            dirtyCheck(this.source)
        );
    }

    initForm(): void {
        this.source = of(cloneDeep(this.form.value));
        this.isDirty$ = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll),
            dirtyCheck(this.source)
        );
    }

    reset(): void {
        this.form.patchValue(this.source);
        this.initForm();
    }
}
```

service-area-editor.component.html

```
<content-editor [formGroup]="form">
   ... my form
</content-editor>
```

dirty-check.ts

```
export function dirtyCheck<U>(source: Observable<U>) {
    let subscription: Subscription;
    let isDirty = false;

    return function <T>(valueChanges: Observable<T>): Observable<boolean> {

        const isDirty$ = combineLatest([
            source,
            valueChanges,
        ]).pipe(
            debounceTime(300),
            map(([a, b]) => {
                console.log(a, b);
                return isDirty = isEqual(a, b) === false;
            }),
            finalize(() => this.subscription.unsubscribe()),
            startWith(false)
        );

        subscription = fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload').subscribe(event => {
            isDirty && (event.returnValue = false);
        });

        return isDirty$;
    };
}
```

How do I get the dirtyCheck operator to work correctly when the form can be anything? I cant supply the dirtyCheck operator with a source stream because the source stream comes from the parent component.

Comment: turn this wrapper into directive and get the access to the form object, or put form in a share service

Comment: Could you please create a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and specify there where is the issue exactly?